# Continuos, surjective map $\pi$ is a quotient map $\iff$ $\pi$ sends saturated open to open or saturated closed to closed

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, quotient-spaces

*Problem is:*

Continuos, surjective map $\pi$ is a quotient map $\iff$ $\pi$ sends saturated open to open or saturated closed to closed.

($U$ is saturated $\iff$ $\exists V \in Y$ s.t. $U = \pi^{-1} (V)$)

*My understanding is:*

First, $U$ is saturated $\iff$ $U= \pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$,

(since 1]: if $U$ is saturated and $x \in \pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$,

then  $\pi(x) \in \pi(U)=\pi(\pi^{-1}(V)) \subset V$ (for some $V \subset Y$),

so that $x\in \pi^{-1}(V)=U$.

The other inclusion is satisfied for all maps.

2]: Converse is immediate by definition of saturated sets.)

Now, Suppose $\pi$ is a quotient map. Let $U$ be saturated and open in $X$.

We will show $\pi(U)$ is open in $Y$

$U = \pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is open in $X$ $\iff$ $\pi(U)$ is open in $Y$,

so $\pi(U)$ is open in $Y$.

Conversely, suppose $\pi$ is surjective and continuous map which sends saturated open sets in $X$ to open set in $Y$.

We will show for any set $V \subset Y$, $V$ is open in $Y \iff \pi^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

If $V$ is open in $Y$, 
then $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is open since $\pi$ is continuous.

Conversely, suppose $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is open in X.

We want to say $V$ is open.

---

Surjectivity implies $V=\pi(U)$ for some $U \subset X$.

$\pi^{-1}(V) = \pi^{-1}(\pi (U))$,

so if $U$ is saturated, $\pi^{-1}(\pi (U)) = U$, and $\pi(U)=V$ is open in $Y$ so we are done.

---

**I think the problem is $U$ cannot be always a saturated set.**

Any hint is welcomed. Thanks.

**Edit**:

Thanks to the comment,

---

This part

---

can be changed as:

Since $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is saturated by definition,
and $\pi$ sends a saturated open set to an open set,

$\pi(\pi^{-1}(V))$ is open in $Y$.

Since $\pi$ is surjective, $V = \pi(\pi^{-1}(V))$, and we are done.

Comment: Hint: $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is saturated.